# Close tkinter window and program with button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI, and I'd like to have a button that closes both the window and exits the program.

I understand that .destroy is supposed to close the window.  When I execute this code, the program hangs, and the window is open but non functional (spinning cursor of death).

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("Title")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        self.closeFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Close Program")
        self.closeFrame.grid(column = 2, row = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)        

        self.buttonclose()

    def buttonclose(self):
        self.buttonclose = ttk.Button(self.closeFrame, text = "Click to Close",command = self.destroy)
        self.buttonclose.grid(column = 1, row = 1)


root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

I have to force quit the window with the above code.

If I add `exit()` to the end of `buttonclose(self)`, then the window closes, BUT I get these warnings:

```
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name clear can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name more can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name less can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name man can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
```

All I want is a button that closes the window and stops the program.  That should be simple, right?

Comment: do you run it in some shell like ipython which has "magic command" ? Did you run it normally in shell/terminal using only `python script .py` ? Your code works correctly for me on Linux.

Comment: Huh.  Good question.  I'm running it in ipython (jupyter notebook).

Comment: I wouldn't run desktop GUI in jupyter notebook which uses web GUI. It seems weird for me :)